# OpenXML's Cell.InnerText is returning nonsense results

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm learning `OpenXML` and running into a strange issue that I can't explain, maybe someone on the forum can explain it and offer a solution.

I've been testing out some code to gather information in individual Excel cells, using some code that looks like this:

```
Cell theCell = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().
            Where(c => c.CellReference == "F4").FirstOrDefault();
            if (theCell != null)
            {
                cellvalue = theCell.InnerText;
                ....
```

It is safe to assume I've called all my `workbook` parts and `sheets`, etc. already.

When I call this routine, and I haven't opened ***Excel*** recently, I can call `Cell.InnerText` and it returns the value that I expect.

But if I open the spreadsheet with ***Excel***, make a change, then close the spreadsheet, calling`Cell.InnerText` returns something strange, a number like "29" or "33".

Does anyone have an idea of why?  Or maybe have a different alternative for getting cell values from Excel in OpenXML?

Comment: I wanted to make a quick clarification.  I am also creating this spreadsheet using OpenXML.  As long as I DON"T OPEN this spreadsheet using Excel (I am using 2010 64-bit) then I can read the spreadsheet just fine using OpenXML.  But if I open the spreadsheet, this is when I start getting all of these problems.

Answer (score 1):

"Or maybe have a different alternative for getting cell values from Excel in OpenXML?"
Yes, it is. Cell has value tag: `<v>`. This tag contains integer. If you cell contains integers, this tag contains this value. But if your cell contains string, this tag contains index of string from xl\sharedStrings.xml part, wehere original cell value stores, so this value contains not the same as your cell value.
I gues when you resave your spreadsheet using Excel, it restructures your document and values could be changed as long as strings were changed indexes in xl\sharedStrings.xml part.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that in the Cell you have type CellValues.SharedString (theCell.DataType) after u make a changes. That type return index of SharedStringTable. To read SharedStringTable use that Code:

```
Dim stringTablePart As SharedStringTablePart = WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType(Of SharedStringTablePart).FirstOrDefault()
If stringTablePart IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each item As SharedStringItem In stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements(Of SharedStringItem)()
        Dim text as string = item.InnerText
    Next
End If
```

I hope this help you.